# How to use a for loop to make multiple graphs of each mean of a column of data per site

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I have a data frame with 20 sites (i.e. levels) and ~ 60 columns of relative abundance of microbial families. I am trying to create a for loop that will find the mean of each family per site. I've been able to do it for one family (see code below) but am not sure how to make a for loop that will automate the process for the rest of the families. Thanks for any help!

```
data.subset = data.all %>%
  select(Site, Enterobacteriaceae) %>%
  group_by(Site) %>%
  summarise(mean(Enterobacteriaceae))

data.subset

pcm = melt(data.subset, id = c("Site"))

pcm$Site <- factor(pcm$Site,levels=unique(pcm$Site))

pcm$Site <- factor(pcm$Site,levels=c("1","2","3","4","5","6", "7","8", "9", "10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","C1", "C2","C3","S1","S2","S3","OF-1","OF-2","OF-3","Effluent","Influent"))

ggplot(pcm, aes(x = Site, fill = variable, y = value)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black")
```

Comment: `melt` data first, aggregate by *Family* and *Site*, and then `ggplot` with `facet_wrap` by *Family*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `summarize(across())` from `dplyr` to get the mean for each of the (60) columns of bacterial families, and then pivot this longer.  Notice that in `across()`, I use `starts_with("F")` to identify the columns, but that is because I have named the columns `F1`, `F2`, `F3`, ... `F60`... Yours might be a range of consecutive columns such as `Enterobactae:Klebsiella`, for example.

```
library(tidyverse)
data.subset = data.all %>%
  group_by(Site) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("F"), ~mean(.x, na.rm=T),.names = "{.col}")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Site, names_to = "Family", values_to = "Relative Abundance")
```

Then, you can use `facet_wrap` to plot a bar plot similar to the one you showed in your original post

```
ggplot(data.subset, aes(x = Site, y =`Relative Abundance`, fill=Family, color=Family )) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~Family) + 
  guides(color="none", fill="none")
```

[image: rel_abundance]

Input Data:

```
set.seed(123)
data.all = data.frame(
  Site = rep(c(1:20), times=30)
)
data.all = cbind(data.all, setNames(as.data.frame(lapply(1:60, function(x) rnorm(600))), paste0("F",str_pad(1:60, width=2,pad = "0"))))
```